# Admin Authorization with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

A have a bunch of controllers with the Admin namespace. I want to restrict access to these unless the user is an admin. Is there a way to do this using CanCan without having to call unauthorized! in every method of every controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an application controller to your namespace and a before filter to it.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end

class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController 
  # these goes in your namespace admin folder
  before_filter :check_authorized

  def check_authorized
    redirect_to root_path unless can? :admin, :all
  end
end

class SomeadminController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def some_action
     # do_stuff
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Admin Namespaces](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace) wiki page for CanCan lists out several solutions to this problem.

- As @mark suggested, have a base controller for admins which checks authorization for every action.

  - You may not need to use CanCan at all for this if all you require is to check that users have an `admin`
    flag.
- For handling admins differently from each other (as opposed to differently from regular users only), 
  consider a separate `AdminAbility` class (this is a little off-topic, but could prove relevant).

Answer (score 0):

now rails_admin has full support with Cancan, you can find it in its official website, there is a wiki page for this topic:

[Rails Admin's authorization with CanCan](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan):

Comment: Did he mention rails_admin?

Comment: yes you are right, he didn't mention rails_admin. I don't suggest using rails_admin since it's no so good as I thought.